# Can I change my notice period while on maternity leave?

Tags: resignation, united-kingdom, notice-period, parental-leave

I have told my current employer that at the end of my maternity leave (June 1st) I will not be returning to work. They have sent me an official acceptance of resignation letter. I have now been offered a job somewhere else but they want me to start a month earlier on 2nd May. Am I able to hand my notice in again to give the required 4 weeks notice to leave on 1st May??
Thank you

Answer (score 5):

The short answer is **yes** - as long as you are still giving your contractual notice you can issue a fresh notice that's shorter than what you've previously given. It's actually a win-win - you get to start your new job when you wanted to and the employer can save on maternity pay, accrued leave pay, employers NI etc!